# Mount a tmpfs folder on startup (volatile) with a created subfolder

Tags: linux, debian, fstab, tmpfs

Currently using Debian 9.5 with this `fstab` file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
/dev/mmcblk1p1  /              ext4   noatime,errors=remount-ro  0  1    
tmpfs           /var/volatile  tmpfs  defaults,x-mount.mkdir     0  0
```

Now, if the folder `/var/volatile` doesn't exist, it will be created (`x-mount.mkdir`).
What would be the correct way of having a subfolder (e.g) like `/var/volatile/subfolder` just created after the mounting procedure succeeds?

I want this subfolder to be created before systemd continues with its tasks until finalizing startup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After exploring systemd, I stumbled upon a greet discovery. It turns out there is no need to create a custom service to deal with this as systemd already provides a solution for this purpose: **`systemd-tmpfiles`**.  It is a structured and configurable method to manage temporary directories and files.

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-tmpfiles.html
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html

Just create a file `/etc/tmpfiles.d/volatile-subfolder.conf` with this content:

```
d       /var/volatile/subfolder 0755 root root - -
```

And reload.

Comment: Why is everyone content to reboot all the time? `
sudo systemd-tmpfiles --create` will do this without a reboot

Answer (score 2):

One way to tackle this would be to create a new systemd service (or modify an exiting one) to handle creating this directory in your `/var/volatile` tempfs using the `After=local-fs.target` unit directive.

```
[Unit]
Description=Tempfs initialize
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=mkdir -p /var/volatile/subfolder


[Install]
WantedBy=multiuser.target
```

Add this to `/etc/systemd/system/tmpfsinit` and then perform the usual `systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl enable tempfsinit`.

Alternatively, if you already have a custom systemd service, you could also add the `After` unit directive and the command to create the subdir you need into a `ExecStartPre` command.

Comment: Thanks `111---` for your input. Much appreciated. For the moment I'm trying to pass by without having to depend on a customized solutions.